# Change element property based on placement of another element - jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-traversing

I'm having trouble working out how I can target a super annoying edgecase I'm having.

How can I target the `h1`, that comes after the `cite` tag?
As `cite` is wrapped inside the `p` tag, I don't know how to traverse out to target it.

The gap between the `cite` (technically the `p`) is too large, yet on 'non-`cite`' paragraphs, it is fine.

**TL:DR** -
Check if a paragraph has a `cite` tag inside of it, then if it does - change the padding-top on the `h1` tag to something less. If the paragraph doesn't have a `cite` inside, leave it untouched.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Jksam

**HTML**

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gentium+Book+Basic:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="post">
    <blockquote>
      <p>
          “Work is the curse of the drinking classes.”
      </p>
    </blockquote>

    <p>
      <cite>
          Oscar Wilde
      </cite>
    </p>

    <h1>
       This is a H1
    </h1>

    <p>
       Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo.
    </p>

    <h1>
       This is a H1
    </h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.post {
  width: 50%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

h1 {
  color: #333332;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  padding-top: 1.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 3.3rem;
}

p + h1 {
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

blockquote {
  border-left: 4px solid #ED5565;
  margin-left: -24px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

cite {
  color: #b3b3b1;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

cite:before {
  content: "- ";
}

blockquote > p {
  padding: 1em; 
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  color: #333332;
  font-family: 'Gentium Book Basic', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.8rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.has()` method or `:has` selector:

```
$('p').has('cite').next('h1').css({'padding-top': 'value'});
```

Assuming all next `h1` siblings of the selected `p` should be selected:

```
$('p').has('cite').nextAll('h1').css({'padding-top': 'value'});
```

Comment: Thank you, you've saved me pulling all of hair out :)

Answer (score 1):

another way would be to start from the cite tag using then use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get to the p tag - then get the next h1 element

```
$('cite').closest('p').next('h1').css('padding-top','50px')
```